# Ajax webform with captcha

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create an ajax contact webform which uses captcha. The form without the captcha works fine, and i can also get the captcha to work on its own (without being validated through ajax).

here is my forms.js this portion specifically validates the form and then posts the information to a php file

```
submitFu:function(){
_.validateFu()
if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:_.mailHandlerURL,
data:{
       name:$('.name input',_.form).val()||'nope',
       email:$('.email input',_.form).val()||'nope',
       phone:$('.phone input',_.form).val()||'nope',
       message:$('.message textarea',_.form).val()||'nope',
       owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
       stripHTML:_.stripHTML
      },
success: function(){
_.showFu()
}
    })          
        },
showFu:function(){
_.form.trigger('reset')
_.success.slideDown(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
_.success.slideUp()

    },_.successShow)
            })
                },
```

for the captcha.php

```
session_start();

//Check if the securidy code and the session value are not blank 
//and if the input text matches the stored text

if ( ($_REQUEST["txtCaptcha"] == $_SESSION["security_code"]) && 
(!empty($_REQUEST["txtCaptcha"]) && !empty($_SESSION["security_code"])) ) {
echo "<h1>True</h1>";
} 
else {
echo "<h1>Incorrect Security Code</h1>";
}
```

and here is the html for the form (the result div is meant to display an incorrect captcha code)

```
<h4>Contact Form</h4>
            <form id="contact-form">
                <div class="success">Contact form submitted! We will be in touch soon </div>
                <fieldset>
                    <label class="name">
                        <input type="text" value="Name:">
                        <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="email">
                        <input type="text" value="E-mail:">
                        <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span>
                        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="phone">
                        <input type="text" value="Phone:">
                        <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span>
                        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="message">
                        <textarea>Message:</textarea>
                        <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span>
                        <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="captcha">Captcha</label>
                    <input id="txtCaptcha" type="text" name="txtCaptcha" value="" maxlength="10" size="32" /> 
                    <img id="imgCaptcha" src="create_image.php" />
                    <div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="btns">
                    <a class="button" data-type="reset">clear</a><a class="button" data-type="submit">send</a></div>
                </fieldset>
```

So what I'm missing is the script for the captcha portion. I have tried the following script and it works with fine on its own (without being part of the form and having its own submit button) but I can't seem to get it to work with the forms.js i posted above

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Mozilla, Safari ...
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //IE
} else {
//Display our error message
alert("Your browser doesn't support the XmlHttpRequest object.");
 }
}

//Our XmlHttpRequest object
var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

//Initiate the AJAX request
function makeRequest(url, param) {
//If our readystate is either not started or finished, initiate a new request
if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
 //Set up the connection to captcha_test.html. True sets the request to asyncronous(default) 
 receiveReq.open("POST", url, true);
 //Set the function that will be called when the XmlHttpRequest objects state changes
 receiveReq.onreadystatechange = updatePage; 

 receiveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 receiveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
 receiveReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

 //Make the request
 receiveReq.send(param);
   }   
  }

 //Called every time our XmlHttpRequest objects state changes
function updatePage() {
//Check if our response is ready
if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
//Set the content of the DIV element with the response text
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;
   //Get a reference to CAPTCHA image
   img = document.getElementById('imgCaptcha'); 
   //Change the image
   img.src = 'create_image.php?' + Math.random();
  }
 }

 //Called every time when form is performed
 function getParam(theForm) {
 //Set the URL
 var url = 'captcha.php';
 //Set up the parameters of our AJAX call
 var postStr = theForm.txtCaptcha.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent( theForm.txtCaptcha.value );
 //Call the function that initiate the AJAX request
 makeRequest(url, postStr);
```

I know it's long and a lot of information. Thank you very much for your time and help
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use reCaptcha for your captcha? They have a brilliant API and have been proven to be the most secure captcha out there.